# Numpy Matrix into an image

Tags: python, image, generator

I have a 2d array with int value that I want to convert into an image.

The 2d array is generated randomly between 1-3, with consideration for what the neighboring int it in the array, I want to convert 1,2,3 to R,G,B in an image to better see what the outcome of the generator is.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) library. Just use `plt.imshow` or `plt.pcolormesh` (the second one is technically better for discrete values). The default colormap is pretty close to RGB in this case, but you could use [another colormap](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) if you wanted to. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Creating random 1-3 data in a 2D array
data = np.random.randint(1,4,[100,150])

plt.pcolormesh(a)
```

[image: Output example]

I'm using [IPython](http://ipython.org/) and `%matplotlib inline`, you might need to call `plt.show()` to get it to draw if you are not using IPython.